# Why use `javascript:` before function call?

Tags: javascript

I have seen at many locations that people use `javascript:` before functions(classes) or using attributes? E.g., `javascript:Blob`, `javascript:void(0)`.

I'm wondering what are the situation when using this notation can be necessary?
Or what're the best practices regarding using or not using this?

Expanding scope of my question:

Can it be useful to use it without `href`. I.e., in JS file directly?

Does ECMAScript have to do anything with it?

Comment: It really shouldn't be necessary at all; inline JavaScript is not a recommended practice.

Comment: Maybe you can find an useful answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0

Comment: It is to tell the browser that the `href` contains Javascript code. Browsers normally expect to find a URL there. You should not put Javascript inside HTML attributes, so now you can forget about this. How fun.

Comment: if you see `onclick="javascript:doSomething()"`, that's just "wrong", likely an amateur mistake (using labels for a non-loop expression).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"javascript:" is a URL protocol. When the browser loads a `javascript:` URL, it takes the rest of the URL as JavaScript code and executes it. Thus, you can put this in an `href` attribute on an `<a>` tag.

It's generally better to not do this, though - instead, you can set `href='#'` and put your JS code in the `onclick` attribute. (Some recommend setting `href='javascript:void(0)'`, which is similar but subtly different. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0).)

Answer (score 0):

This is usually used for HTML a tag HREF's ie `<a href="javascript:function();">LINK TEXT</a>`

Comment: He asked about best practice, this is totally beyond of bad practice please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0

Comment: Read the question carefully before answering.The question is why and not where javascript: is used

Comment: No, the question was "what are the situation when using this notation can be necessary" - it is never necessary to have JavaScript URIs inside a `href`` attribute, as attaching event handlers is a preferred mechanism.